# Examples of Change of baseline vs Final values

Tags: meta-analysis, measurement, pre-post-comparison

I'm learning how to perform a meta-analysis from the Cochrane handbook: http://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_7/7_7_3_1_post_intervention_versus_change_from_baseline.htm

Here they talk about the difference between reporting Change of Baseline values and reporting Final (Post-intervention) values. In my experience, I have only ever seen change of baseline measured. When would final values only be used, and what's an example?

As someone with a life science background, it seems useless to only have final values. e.g. Testing the effect of nitroglycerin on blood pressure, you want to see the DROP in blood pressure - it doesn't mean anything if you only have the final value

Comment: Post-test only control design - experimental design with randomly formed groups, treatment, and posttest; no pretest. It has sometimes been documented that incorporating a pretest can affect performance on a posttest, so this design eliminates pretest as a confounder. If groups randomly formed, and large, theory suggests groups likely equivalent on confounders, so examining only posttest can provide evidence of treatment effect without need for pretest. Solomon four group design can be used to assess pretest effect.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan. Can you expand on "incorporating a pretest can affect performance on a posttest?" Is this a situation where perhaps the detection/test method can be stressful on the subject, or in some other way influence the procedure?

Comment: Yes, a pretest may sensitize one to future treatments and cause greater or less outcomes compared to those who did not experience a pretest. The link below is for a study on mammography use. Table 3 provides the critical results, those with pretest+treatment had higher test rates than those with only the treatment. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3630258/

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, I would like to have a baseline and end of experiment value in any controlled experiment. Whether you then analyze the final value or the change from baseline is the same thing sas far as the difference to the control group is concerned, if you adjust for the baseline. The difference to the control group is what matters, while the change from baseline may occur for any number of reasons. Sometimes reporting one or the other (change or final value) might be considered more useful by some, but that's usually personal preference.

However, sometimes you can only measure something once, e.g. organ weight after dissecting an animal, SAT score at end of school career etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just to clarify, for the first paragraph, reporting the change from baseline and reporting both the initial and final values are essentially the same thing? The examples make a lot of sense though.

Comment: It depends, if they fit a statistical model (e.g. ANCOVA) adjusting for baseline, then yes. If they analyze each without adjustment for baseline, then not quite (there's a Stephen Senn paper discussing the nuances of that).

Comment: A note- if using ANCOVA (or regression) and adjusting for pretest (baseline), the F or t-test comparing groups will be the same whether analyzing gain score or posttest (final score), but the adjusted scores will have different meanings. For gains, the adjusted or predicted group means will be the adjusted gain for each group, but for posttest, the adjusted means will be the adjusted posttest. So the inferential test provides the same F or t-ratio (and therefore same p-value), but the interpretation of adjusted means differ, in one it is adjusted gain and the other adjusted posttest.